# Finding the Smallest and the Largest Circles Among Circles that Pass a Given Point and Are Tangent to a Given Circle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

We are given a circle, say $S$, and a point, say $P$, inside $S$. I want to find the radius of the smallest and the largest circles that pass through $P$ and touche $S$ (internally).

Intuitively it is clear that diameters of such circles can be chosen to be along the diameter of $S$ that passes through $P$. But I am unable to prove it.

I suppose there is a role of triangle inequality but I am not able see the useful triangles.

How can I prove this "obvious" fact?

Comment: Let Q be the touching point, and T the tangent to Q. Now T is tangent to both circles, implying both circle midpoints $M_1$ and $M_2$, P and Q are all colinear, as $M_1$T and $M_2$T and PT are all perpendiculars to T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, the triangle inequality plays a role. As a rule of thumb, when there is a tangent point, we should draw the segment between the center of the circle and the tangent point.

---

Let $O$ be the center of $S$. Let $QR$ be the diameter of $S$ that pass through $P$, where $Q$ is nearer to $P$ than $R$. (Please check the special case when $P$ is $O$.)
[image]
Suppose another circle with center $X$ passes through $P$ and touches $S$ at $Y$, where $Y$ is neither $Q$ nor $R$ (Please check what happens if $Y$ is either $Q$ or $R$). Then $X$ is on the segment between $O$ and $Y$.

$$\begin{aligned} PQ&=OQ-OP=OY-OP\\
&< YP\\
&< XY+XP\end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned} PR&=OR+OP=OY+OP\\
&=(XY+OX)+OP\\
&> XY+XP \end{aligned}$$

Since $XY+XP$ is two times the radius of the inner circle,  we are done.

##### An exercise

What happens if $P$ is outside of $S$? Prove your conclusion.

Comment: Short and crispy! Thank you! If $P$ lies outside of $S$, I proved the assertion for the smallest circle. But for the largest circle, say $T$, I am confused. I am not sure whether $S$ would completely inside $T$ or some part of $S$ lies outside $T$.

Comment: There is no largest circle. A circle that passes $P$ and touches $S$ can be arbitrarily large.